# Vistaprint says it accepts PSD files, but won't accept mine

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-format

On the Vistaprint website it says that PSD format is recommended, but it won't allow me to select my PSD file. It says CS3 Image. I'm currently using PS CC 2019.

"We support a variety of file formats for uploaded designs.
Adobe Acrobat 9 Document (*.pdf) (recommended)
Adobe Illustrator CS3 Artwork (*.ai) (recommended)
Adobe Photoshop CS3 Image (*.psd) (recommended)
Bitmap Image (*.bmp)
GIF Image (*.gif)
JPEG Image (*.jpg,*.jpeg)
Microsoft PowerPoint 2010 Document (*.ppt)
Microsoft Word 2010 Document (*.doc)
PCX Image (*.pcx)
PICT Image (*.pic,*.pict,*.pct)
PNG Image (*.png)
PostScript Document (*.ps)
TIFF Image (*.tif,*.tiff)"

Comment: Creative Suite 3 (CS3) is NOT CC2019.

Comment: Oh I see. Why wouldn't it work tho since the files are still .psd ?

Comment: Any recommendations for the best quality print?

Comment: Simply they may not have a cc subscription

Comment: "Why wouldn't it work?" - because earlier versions of Photoshop often can't open PSDs from later versions.  There is little to no backwards compatibility with PSDs. Try PDF instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to save to the CS3 legacy PS file format. If not just save it as a PDF and submit it that way.

Answer (score 0):

PSD CS3 is quite an old legacy format and it may not be 100% compatible with the latest CC format, Vistaprint may require this for technical reasons.

That text you pasted clearly says a PDF format is also recommended. If that won't work try JPG or TIFF which are also listed.